# Help with computer math project

Tags: python

I need help making a program that would calculate 1+x+x^2+...+x^n for a given x and a positive integer n and use it to calculate (1+x+x^2+...+x^10)(1+x^2+x^2...+x^10) for x=100

so far i have

```
def myfunc(x, n, step): 
  if n > 0: 
    return x**n + myfunc(x, n - step, step) 
  return 1 #In case n is 0
```

I would then use myfunc(100,10, 1)*myfunc(100,10,2) to get the answer.
However, i have been recently informed that the function shouldn't contain any variable and should calculate the answer without putting any variables.  So for example, it would be myfunc() and would calculate the same answer.  How should I change my program so that it would still calculate the same answer?

Comment: If you want the function to be able to work with any x and n, then you have to tell it what x and n are. There's no getting around that.

Comment: waht do you mean by shouldn't contain any variable?

Comment: as in i have to make a program so def myfunc(): and it would calculate the same answer if you use my original program

Comment: you need at least the `n` variable to perform the recursion (if recursion is the point of the homework)

Answer (score 6):

Hint, since the "functional-programming" tag is present, I assume it is an exercise in recursion:

```
1 + x + x**2 + ... + x**n = 1 + x * (1 + x + ... + x**(n-1))
```

You only need n multiplications and no exponentiation to evaluate this polynomial. This is called the *Horner scheme*. Note that this formula can also be implemented in a for loop: try to compute the value of 1 + ... + x^n with a pen and paper, using only n multiplications and deduce the algorithm.

Another hint, depending on what your teacher/advisor/mom wants:

```
1 + x + ... + x**n = (x**(n+1) - 1) / (x - 1).
```

Comment: The functional programming tag was present because someone (not the OP) added it for some reason I don't understand. You shouldn't take that as a sign of the OP's intent.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, I see. That's why I provide two hints. But since OP uses recursion in its approach and this smells like homework, I give both.

Comment: Maybe as a hint how to arrive at the 2nd formula: I thought "this would be simple for x=2 -- I know that sum is `(x**(n+1)-1` because that's how binary numbers work" ... so I tried to generalize that idea and found it.

Comment: @THC4k: or simply by expanding (x - 1)(1 + x + ... + x^n) and noticing that almost all terms cancel.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc(x, n, step): 
  if n > 0: 
    return x**n + calc(x, n - step, step) 
  return 1 #In case n is 0

def myfunc()
  return calc(100,10,1)*calc(100,10,2)
```

to hard code the numbers in that would be the only way to get the answer with out supplying arguments,

Comment: well i suppose unless theres another way to evaluate it i guess not, but using the method you provided